# How to override Elgg's user icon upload action

Tags: php, action, elgg

I've been trying to override the default user icon action.

**my_plugin/classes/Elgg/MyHooksOverrides/EntityIconOverride.php** :

```
<?php

namespace Elgg\MyHooksOverrides;

class EntityIconOverride {
    public function __invoke(\Elgg\Hook $hook) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**my_plugin/elgg-plugin.php** :

```
<?php

return [
    'plugin' => [
        'name' => 'My Plugin',
        'activate_on_install' => true,
    ],
    'view_extensions' => [],
    'hooks' => [
        'prepare' => [
            'entity:avatar:prepare' => [
                \Elgg\MyHooksOverrides\EntityIconOverride::class => [],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

I've also tried this setup with `entity:icon:prepare` :

```
<?php

return [
    'plugin' => [
        'name' => 'My Plugin',
        'activate_on_install' => true,
    ],
    'view_extensions' => [],
    'hooks' => [
        'prepare' => [
            'entity:avatar:prepare' => [
                \Elgg\MyHooksOverrides\EntityIconOverride::class => [],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

However, this is not having any effect. The hook should prevent the upload from proceeding, but the upload goes on successfully meaning that the plugin hook never gets called.

How can I make sure that my plugin hook gets called / OR, in other words, how can I override the default user icon upload action?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should override `'avatar/upload'` action:

```
return [
    'plugin' => [
        'name' => 'My Plugin',
        'activate_on_install' => true,
    ],
    'actions' => [
        'avatar/upload' => [
             'controller' => \MyPlugin\Actions\AvatarUpload::class,
         ],
    ],
];
```

[Elgg docs](https://learn.elgg.org/en/stable/guides/actions.html).

Also, you can use ['action/validate'](https://learn.elgg.org/en/stable/guides/hooks-list.html#action-hooks) hook:

By the way, I don't recommend use `\Elgg` namespace in your custom plugin.
Use `\MyPlugin` instead